# List does not exist Error when adding web part Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list, web-part

I want to add a web part in my site collection home page containing a list that is created in on of the subsites... i looked in Google for that and it looked like a simple task to do.

Almost all blogs describes the same steps which are :

1. Open the list in SPD
2. Edit the desired View
3. in webPart section in the ribbon save to file click
4. import the .webPart file

And this should be working, however every time i get the `"List does not exist it might have been deleted by another user ..."` error

I tried doing this from multiple subsites levels and different sites, it seems like i cannot add a webPart conataining a list in lower level site

Ps: when i add the webPart in the site home page (the site where the list is created) it works and the list is displayed...

Am i missing something?

(I am using SharePoint 2013 on permises)

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: double check with this http://mroffice365.com/2012/01/sharepoint-display-a-list-or-library-from-subsite-to-the-top-level-site/

Comment: yeah, i did fellow that article and others like it... still having the same error

Comment: In Fact, i don't know why i never get the warning message telilng "You want this webPart to show list data from the current website..."